# Can I drive a tablet from an external touchscreen monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I'd like to drive a tablet running windows 7 or 8 pro from an external touchscreen monitor.  I  know the tablet will accept a USB mouse input and will output HDMI to the monitor, so it should work, but has any one done this before?  Not sure if there may be some issues or constraints with it.  I'd also like the screen to be in portrait orientation.

Thanks.